# How catch event from "event-changing" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have two `<textarea></textarea>` and one `<div></div>`.

If I change text in `#first` textarea, this text copied in `#second` textarea. How I may catch event, that if text in `#second` textarea changed, I change text in div `#needle`? Which event?

Events `change keyup paste input propertychange` don't work..

I don't want to use compulsory event `$('#second').change()` in first event..

```
<textarea id="first"></textarea>
<textarea id="second"></textarea>
<div id="needle"></div>

<script>
    $('#first').keyup(function(){
         $('#second').val($(this).val());   
    });

    $(document).on('change keyup paste input propertychange', '#second', function(){
        $('#needle').text($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjvP5/)

Comment: You have to trigger the event programmatically.

Comment: without manually firing the change event, other choice to move the code `$('#needle').text($(this).val());` to the first handler also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event is uncreated in jquery..

Answer (score 1):

`input` event is enough.

I would recommend you to create a function like `changeText` that you call when `input` even is triggered in the second textarea and when you update the text in it.

```
$('#first').on("input", function(){
    changeText.call(
      $('#second').val( // <- You update the second textarea value
         $(this).val()  //    with the text from the first textarea
      )                 // <- This will return the second textarea jQuery object
    );
});

$(document).on('input', '#second', changeText);

function changeText() {
    // here `this` will be the second textarea jQuery object 
    $('#needle').text($(this).val());
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjvP5/3/)

Comment: *I don't want to use compulsory event $('#second').change() in first event..*?

Comment: @Ionică Bizău It's the same and update two elements.. Really there are no other events?

Comment: @Luntegg According [to this](http://jsfiddle.net/ErY4z/) there is no other event that you can catch...

Answer (score 0):

you should use "change" event:

```
$('#second').on('change', function(){
 $('needle').append($(this).val()); // this appends the value 
});
```

Note that we are using `append()` method. If we use `html()` or `text()`, we literally override the `#needle` value on each change occurrence which  probably look strange and unsual (and unusable perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a named function instead of using anonymous function.

```
function onChangeSecond()
{
 $('#needle').text($(this).val());
}
```

you can use onChageSecond() in keyUp Events of First and Second Textarea.